# Doc2Vec or Word2vec for word embedding

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embeddings, information-retrieval

Is there any benefits from using Doc2vec for word embedding ( replacing word2vec ) ? in other hand if I train word2vec and doc2vec with the same dataset will I have the same word vectors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, *doc2vec* generates vectors representing documents (sentences, paragraphs) but not single words. So training *doc2vec* won't give you word vectors but document vectors. This means you can't replace *word2vec* by *doc2vec* at all.

Here's how the authors of the [underlying paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4053) describe what doc2vec does:

> Our algorithm represents each document by a dense vector which is trained to predict words in the document.